# C++ inheritance, templates, and override

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm having some trouble formalizing an interface to a template class. Why does the following compile?

```
class IFoo {
public:
    virtual void functionA()=0;
};

template<class T>
class Foo : public IFoo{
public:
    void functionA() override { };
    void functionB() override { };
};
```

functionB obviously does not exist in IFoo, so why is the compiler not throwing an error? Currently running on GCC 5.4.

A bit of background as to how I came to this issue: I'm putting together some code for a side project of mine which depends heavily on common linear algebra routines. I want to abstract over the choice of library in order to e.g. facilitate benchmarking. The idea is to use an interface like IFoo to do this, so that the business logic code only knows about IFoo rather than have to accomodate the quirks of any single linear algebra lib. This is feasible because there are only a handful of key functions that are necessary; I'm not looking to provide an interface for all available operations. I need the templates to allow for processing using different degrees of precision, e.g. float, double, minifloats, etc. to be handled by the same subclass.

In my head a sensible design for this problem is re-wrapping access to these libs with this interface in separate compilation units to produce independent static or runtime libraries that implement this interface. Switcing from one lib to another would then be as simple as linking against the desired library; no changes in code are necessary. Any thoughts on this general strategy also appreciated!

Comment: Your code example does not show whether you are actually creating fully specialized forms of the template - could you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks, this was precisely the issue, was not aware of that behavior, but it makes sense now that its pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates are instantiated only if some other code uses them. Your example doesn't have that code so it really doesn't matter whether this compiles or not. Try creating an object of `Foo<int>` and see for yourself that GCC will then complain.

Comment: *"it really doesn't matter whether this compiles or not"* - more to the point, it must be parseable (you cannot just put random characters in there, mind you! :)), but no diagnostic is required by the compiler if the successfully parsed template cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

You only defined a class template but you did not instantiate it. Excerpt from the [template reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template):

> A class template by itself is not a type, or an object, or any other
>   entity. No code is generated from a source file that contains only
>   template definitions. In order for any code to appear, a template must
>   be instantiated:

If you tried to instantiate an object with:

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<IFoo> p = std::make_unique<Foo<void>>();
}
```

then GCC would complain with:

> error: 'void Foo::functionB() [with T = void]' marked 'override',
>   but does not override
>   void functionB() override { };

[Live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ddcece343c05f4b)
While the above compiles on VS if you tried to call a member function with:

```
p->functionB();
```

you would receive the following errors:

> 'functionB' : is not a member of 'IFoo'
>   class "IFoo" has no member
>   "functionB"

That being said it is unclear where in your class you are actually using the template. If you removed the `template<class T>` you would get the errors you expected in the first place.